# PHP create form wont recognize index

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a form that applies the CRUD functions using HTML/PHP and mySQL. I'm able to delete, read, and update but am unable to create a new record. Below is my database structure, index page, and create page. Any guidance appreciated. I did not include the config file because I did not find it necessary. The name of the database Thanks!

**exact error**

Notice: Undefined index: rank in C:\xampp\htdocs\Update\create.php on line 30

[image: Database structure]

**create.php**

```
// Include config file
require_once "config.php";

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$nickname = $lastsubmission = $rank = "";
$nickname_err = $lastsubmission_err = $rank_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    // Validate name
    $input_nickname = trim($_POST["nickname"]);
    if(empty($input_nickname)){
        $nickname_err = "Please enter a name.";
    } elseif(!filter_var($input_nickname, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/")))){
        $nickname_err = "Please enter a valid name.";
    } else{
        $nickname = $input_nickname;
    }

    // Validate address
    $input_lastsubmission = trim($_POST["lastsubmission"]);
    if(empty($input_lastsubmission)){
        $lsstsubmission_err = "Please enter an address.";     
    } else{
        $lastsubmission = $input_lastsubmission;
    }

    // Validate salary
    $input_rank = trim($_POST["rank"]);
    if(empty($input_rank)){
        $rank_err = "Please enter the salary amount.";     
    } elseif(!ctype_digit($input_rank)){
        $rank_err = "Please enter a positive integer value.";
    } else{
        $rank = $input_rank;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your *nickname* element in the HTML form needs the *name* attribute. Likely a copy/paste error?

Same applies to all your other HTML input elements.

Change `nickname="nickname"` to `name="nickname"`.

```
<input type="text" name="nickname" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $nickname; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you assign $param_nickname after you bind it with mysqli_stmt_bind_param

```
//First Set parameters
$param_nickname = $nickname;
$param_lastsubmission = $lastsubmission;
$param_rank = $rank;

//Then Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $param_nickname, 
$param_lastsubmission, $param_rank);
```

should do the trick